# Adjust arrow position to match the middle of the referencing element

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have two elements, a reference element, illustrated by a black, rounded button, and a wider component, that resembles a popover, with a pointer. Unlike most popovers on the internet, I decided to go with relative positioning, because I want it to continue occupying the space.

The problem is that, by using `react-popper`, it seems like it can't handle the positioning too well. If you take a look at the Sandbox sample below, the arrow is not pointing towards the middle of the rounded button.

The components code, nothing special, just made this to illustrate my big problem. Here's the button, pretty basic.

```
import { forwardRef } from "react";

export const RoundedBtn = forwardRef(({ children }, ref) => {
  return (
    <button className="btn" ref={ref}>
      {children}
    </button>
  );
});
```

And the Popover

```
import { forwardRef } from "react";

export const Popover = forwardRef(
  ({ title, footer, popoverProps, children }, ref) => {
    const { popperStyles, arrowStyles } = popoverProps;

    return (
      <div className="popover" ref={ref}>
        {title && <header>{title}</header>}
        {children}
        {footer && <footer>{footer}</footer>}
        <span data-popper-arrow style={arrowStyles} className="popover-arrow" />
      </div>
    );
  }
);
```

Forwarded refs in both components, in Popover I'm using the popper styles to apply it to the arrow (I haven't done so to the Popover container, because it applies `position: absolute` to it and I don't want it).

In App.js, again, simple:

```
export default function App() {
  const [refEl, setRefEl] = useState(null);
  const [popOverRef, setPopoverRef] = useState(null);

  const {
    styles: { popper, arrow }
  } = usePopper(refEl, popOverRef, {
    placement: "top"
  });

  const popoverProps = {
    popperStyles: popper,
    arrowStyles: arrow
  };

  return (
    <div className="app example-1">
      <RoundedBtn ref={setRefEl}>+</RoundedBtn>
      <Popover
        popoverProps={popoverProps}
        ref={setPopoverRef}
        title={title}
        footer={footer}
      >
        {content}
      </Popover>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Just using `usePopper` hook and setting its needed refs.

But, please see this live because it's not aligned correctly.
https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-tess-jtz61e

Can you instruct me what steps to take in order to fix this? It shouldn't matter the technique we use to move the ref and popper elements, we can use `align-items: center` (which oddly seems to work fine with the arrow), or `align-items: flex-end`, the arrow should still be pointing at the referencing element, or very approximately.

Please help, I would very much appreciate it, it's been driving me insane.

Answer (score 0):

pass this CSS property for the second popover

```
transform: translate(8px, 0px);
```

[image]

Comment: And how did you get that value?

Comment: @florinpavel by browser inspect,